# Find string that contains substring from redirected file, but keep getting Seg-fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, substring, strstr

The program requires me to find strings that contain substrings (specified in the command line argument) from a redirected file (filetoreadfrom.data). The file contains a list of words(strings). If the strings contain the substrings, then print the strings. The command line is as follows:

> ./program substring < filetoreadfrom.data

I keep getting *"Segmentation-fault (Core dumped)"* error message and I don't know why. At first I thought it's because of not malloc'ing my char array, but now that I've get rid of it by fixing the size of the char array using **#define MAXchar 200**, I really can't see what went wrong. Is it because of the memory space, my usage of fgets or strstr, or something wrong with the way I'm redirecting the file.

These are my codes:

```
    char line[MAXchar]; //MAXchar = 200
    int count=0;

    //check usage
    if ((strcmp("<", argv[2]))!=0){
            fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./program substring\n");
            return 1;
    }

    //read lines from redirected file
    while (fgets(line,MAXchar,stdin)!=NULL){
            //find substring in each line
            //if substring is present in the line
            if (strstr(line,argv[1])!=NULL){
                    //print the line
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", line);
                    count=1;
            }
    }
    //if none of the line contains the substring
    if (count==0){
            fprintf(stdout, "No match found\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

}

I hope you guys can shed some light in this. Thanks!

Comment: I think there may be many issues .. you are not checking the number of arguments.  The '<' is swallowed by the shell and does not come to the program.

Answer (score 2):

it crashes when you check for `argv[2]`. there is no `argv[2]`, as the `<` is a console/shell specific command which isn't passed through to your program. At the time you check argv[2] it's a NULL pointer, and you do not have permission to write/read there. that's why the segfault occurs.

e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("%d\n", argc);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./test < test.c
1
$
```

Comment: Actually `argv[]` is `NULL`-terminated, so it's a `NULL` pointer dereference. Just as bad, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `< filetoreadfrom.data` means use filetoreadfrom.data as `stdin`.

So you program only got two param ： `./program substring`

In you code, remove this part :

```
if ((strcmp("<", argv[2]))!=0){
            fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./program substring\n");
            return 1;
    }
```

If you wonder user forget using `< filetoreadfrom.data` , may be you can pass the `filetoreadfrom.data` by  `./program substring  filetoreadfrom.data` and open it ,

then use `dup` to copy the file description to `STDIN_FILENO`. or just read from it.

You can check the`argc != 3`to make sure user give a input file.

Answer (score 0):

With that command line `argv[2]` will be `NULL`. So the line

```
if ((strcmp("<", argv[2]))!=0){
```

will give segmentation fault.

You may want to do

```
if(argc < 2) {
    //show usage
}
```